# Monitoring Undertow by Statsd

Tags: spring-boot, jmx, undertow, statsd

I want to monitor Undertow (mainly IO and worker threads) using statsd, I had in place tomcat and a lot of metrics were exported automatically to jmx but it seems not the case for Undertow.

I can see XNIO on JConsole for the application(Spring-boot app), but no metrics appear when I try to see them anywhere else.(Graphite, Datadog)